# Scheduling Text Messages with Cron

Tags: node.js, cron, push-notification

I would like to schedule text message reminders for user created events in my web based application. The events are saved to Mongodb Atlas with an ISO for start time.

Initial thought was to use 'node-cron' set to run a database query to retrieve and send reminders to events with a start time equal to the current time, but running a cron job and db query every minute seems resource heavy.

My next thought was to create a cron job for each event, that would reduce the number of db queries. Issue is that I am not sure how to update the app.js node file to include each new cron job, it also sounds resource heavy.

Are either of these viable or is there another way?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a message broker to. In the message broker, you can use a delay every time there is incoming data. The ones from message brokers you can resend to your app, message brokers that use delays are rabbitmq and NSQ. You can read the documentation here for rabbit mq: https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-delayed-message-exchange